# making a class private so the value doesn't get modified

Tags: c#, arrays

I am looking to make the tile class be private; in particular it should not be able to change the value of the tile after it has been constructed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Tiles
{
    class tile
    {
         readonly int[,] arr;//added this 
         public int [,] Print2DArray(int n)
        {
            int[,] arr;
            do
            {
                Random random = new Random();
                arr= new int[n, n];
                int k = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                        arr[i, j] = k++;
                    }
                }
```

This `returns` to the main program, the tile and main program are separate .cs files how would I make it so the value after returning doesn't get modified.

main:

```
Tile mytiles = new Tile();
int[,] original = mytiles.Print2DArray(n);
```

Comment: There are no fields...

Comment: add read only indexer to `Tiles` class so you can access `arr` values without direct access

Answer (score 0):

To make a value such that it cannot be redefined [use `const`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const)

Your tile class should 1) start with a capital letter 2) have a proper constructor 3) have properties with only getters or [`readonly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly) if you want the Tile class to be *immutable* (not private)

Comment: But OP is generating result at runtime how will const help in this case

Comment: *how would I make it so the value after returning doesn't get modified* - const applies to local variables too

Comment: I dont know if I edited it right according to your suggestions

Comment: @derek Why not just use a constructor to create your array and store it as a field rather that return it as a method? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors

Answer (score 0):

The accessibility modifier of a class only affects the visibility of this class type. It does not influence the mutability of the fields or properties. If you want to make a class immutable, you can initialize it in the constructor and use read-only properties or fields.

You can achieve this through a getter-only property or a read-only field. They can only be initialized through an initializer or in the class constructor. But note that the elements of the array are still read/write. But since the array is private, it cannot be changed from outside.

Example:

```
public class Tile
{
    private static readonly _random = new Random();

    private readonly int _n;
    private readonly int[,] _matrix;

    // Class constructor
    public Tile(int n)
    {
        _n = n;
        _matrix = new int[n, n];

        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                arr[i, j] = k++;
            }
        }
    }

    // This indexer allows you to retrieve entries from the 2D-array,
    // but not to change them.
    public int this[int i, int j]
    {
        get { return _matrix[i, j]; }
    }

    // Returns a copy of the original array.
    public int[,] MatrixClone()
    {
        return (int[,])_matrix.Clone();
    }

    public void Print() // No `n` parameter required, since the array 
                        // size is known and cannot be changed.
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
Tile mytiles = new Tile(5);
mytiles.Print();
int value = mytiles[2, 0];
mytiles[2, 0] = 42; // DOES  NOT COMPILE!
int[,] clone = mytiles.MatrixClone();
// Now, you can modify `clone` without modifying the original inside the tile.
clone[2, 0] = 42; // Works.
```